# Q: illegal string offset JSON -> PHP

Tags: php, json

I already view a lot of questions in stackoverflow about my problem, but I didn't find any solution. I don't know where is the problem in my code? I got illegal string offset message at this row:

```
echo $value["country"] . ", " . $value["competition"] . "<br>";
```

My full code:

```
<?php

// file_get_contents call instead
$str = file_get_contents('general.json');

$json = json_decode($str,true);

 foreach($json as $key => $value){

echo $value["country"] . ", " . $value["competition"] . "<br>";

}
?>
```

my json source sample:

```
["{\"country\":\"America\",\"competition\":\"Copa America\",\"club\":\"BOCA JUNIORS\"}","{\"country\":\"Germany\",\"competition\":\"Bundesliga\",\"club\":\"HANNOVER\"}","{\"country\":\"Asia\",\"competition\":\"JLeague\",\"club\":\"NAGOYA\"}"]
```

If I view format of the data with var_dump($json) then I see it is an Array. With var_dump($value) then I see there is a string. Please help for me where is the problem in my code, why could not echo value country and value competition?

Comment: For the future, try and use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) as well!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have json that has been encoded twice, both the array and the elements in the array.

You should avoid doing that, but if you cannot change the source, you need to decode the values as well:

```
<?php
// file_get_contents call instead
$str = file_get_contents('general.json');

$json = json_decode($str,true);

foreach($json as $key => $value){
    // decode the $value string
    $value = json_decode($value, true);

    echo $value["country"] . ", " . $value["competition"] . "<br>";

}
?>
```

[An example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eDLw1O).

Comment: I've been looking for this for hours. Thanks a lot.